# WordPress - Can't get directly cookies

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, setcookie

I can't get cookie value after set it .

`Notice: Undefined index: posts_notification` while it's set.

functions.php :

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_setcookie_example' );
function my_setcookie_example() {
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['posts_notification'])){
        setcookie( 'posts_notification', 'value', time() + 60,COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
    }
}
// The problem is here :
print_r($_COOKIE['posts_notification'] );
```

i should refresh **2** time to get this value !!!

Comment: Try with cache disabled

Comment: @RubyRacer it's not from cashe .